# Implement Custom FormsAuthenticationModule and replace the default

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, forms-authentication

I cannot find any information on how to implement custom `FormsAuthenticationModule`.

Specifically, I want to implement a `MyFormsAuthentication` that mirrors most features of `FormsAuthenticationModule`, or child of `FormsAuthenticationModule`

```
<httpModules>
  ...
  <add name="FormsAuthentication"
       type="System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule" />
  ...
</httpModules>
```

`MyFormsAuthentication` can be used by the element in web.config, instead of the default `FormsAuthenticationModule`:

```
<authentication mode="Forms" />
```

The reason is that I want to support the domains format below:

Set A

```
a.domain.com

a.x.domain.com

a.y.domain.com
```

Can share cookie within set A.

Set B

```
b.domain.com

b.x.domain.com

b.y.domain.com
```

Can share cookie within set B.

Cookies (including Forms Authentication cookie) cannot be shared between domains of set A and set B, but use the same code base.

**Current implemention**

`FormsAuthenticationTicket` is used to generate forms auth cookie.

Any idea, or better solution?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480476.aspx